# I want to access internet on ubuntu 12.04.1 guest system from windows 7 64bit host in virtualbox 4.1.18 How to do so?

Tags: networking, windows-7, internet-connection

I am using Windows 7 64bit as host system and i have installed ubuntu 12.04.1 in virtual box as stated above. I have a dsl connection which works well on my host system and now I need to access the same connection on my guest ubuntu. I cant see any such settings in ubuntu. I am total biginner and dont know anything about linux. Win 7 is showing unknown network. Please guide me from the scratch. Thank you.

---

Yeah thats the thing. It is NAT but I could not see that the network is working fine. Win 7 says unidentified network. So they are not yet networked and I thing it should be networking and internet access sharing to be done. Please guide. Thank you.

And now its working fine without any change made by me or anyone. I dont know what is this miracle any idea?

Comment: By default everything is configured automatically in Ubuntu and VirtualBox. Your network configuration in Windows nicht be wrong, but hat is not related to Ubuntu.

Comment: For the virtual network to function properly, VirtualBox install drivers on Windows 7. Maybe at first there was some problems with them, or you needed to restart Windows. It probably will work without problems for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you created the Virtual Machine with default options, the network interface should be set to NAT.
Which means if your host has access to the internet, your guest should too.
Could you go to the guest settings, and check how's the network configuration?